# Connect DVR camera using Java opencv

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am developing cctv surveillance system using java & I want to connect dvr cameras(http://admin@192.168.1.101/cgi-bin/view.cgi?chn=1&u=admin&p=%22). I got some suggestion to use opencv library. I got video stream from laptop webcam but when i try with dvr ip i am not able to get video stream. I found the similar question on stack overflow but it doesn't have any answer & doesn't full fill my needs.

I used following code

```
package opencvdemo;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class VideoStream
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("opencv start..");

        // Load native library
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        VideoCapture camView=new VideoCapture();

        camView.open(0);

        if(!camView.isOpened())
        {
            System.out.println("Camera Error..");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Camera successfully opened");
        }

        videoCamera cam=new videoCamera(camView);

        //Initialize swing components
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        frame.add(cam);
        frame.setSize(1080,720);  
        frame.setVisible(true);

        while(camView.isOpened())
        {
            cam.repaint();
        }
    }        
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
        class videoCamera extends JPanel
{
    VideoCapture camera; 

    public videoCamera(VideoCapture cam) 
    {
        camera  = cam; 
    }

    public BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat m)
    {
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        if (m.channels() > 1)
        {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        }
        int bufferSize = m.channels() * m.cols() * m.rows();
        byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
        m.get(0, 0, b); // get all the pixels
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(m.cols(), m.rows(), type);
        final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);
        return img;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Mat mat = new Mat();

        if( camera.read(mat))
        {
            System.out.print("IMAGE");
        }

        BufferedImage image = Mat2BufferedImage(mat);

        g.drawImage(image,10,10,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), null);
    }
    public Mat turnGray( Mat img)
    {
        Mat mat1 = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img, mat1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        return mat1;
    }
    public Mat threash(Mat img)
    {
        Mat threshed = new Mat();
        int SENSITIVITY_VALUE = 100;
        Imgproc.threshold(img, threshed, SENSITIVITY_VALUE,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
        return threshed;
    }
}
```

when I give DVR camera ip insted of 0 in camView.open() it doesn't work
Can any one suggest me some solution to solve this problem.

Comment: if you're on win, make sure it can find the opencv_ffmpegXXX.dll

Comment: I didn't got any error. But it gives "Camera error...." which i given in following if condition. `if(!camView.isOpened()) { System.out.println("Camera Error.."); }` It should go to the else statement which is "Camera successfully opened" my dvr ip is
"http://admin@192.168.1.101:80/cgi-bin/view.cgi?chn=1&u=admin&p="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. I placed **opencv_ffmpeg.dll** in "**c:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin**" folder and it worked. try it...